# Правильно ли делаю параллельные задачи?

Tags: python, asyncio, android-asynctask

У меня есть таблица в базе данных, которая содержит запросы, которые будут отправлены в будущем. И мне нужно, чтобы все задачи (отправка, уменьшение времени, проверка пользователей, проверка премиум) были параллельны друг другу и, чтобы они не мешали друг другу при выполнении.

Я решил сделать так. Создать таски, которые будут отличаться друг от друга и каждый занимается своим. Но проблема в том, что пока не выполниться, например таск1, то не выполниться таск2. (возможно ошибаюсь, но мне так кажется при выполнении кода)

Вот основная функция:

```
async def startTimerRequests():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Ожидание 60 секунд (1 минута)
        print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + 'новый круг')

        # Проверяем все реквесты и если время подошло, то отправляем их
        users = await database.getAllUsers()
        requests_with_0 = await database.getAllRequestsWhereTime_is_0()
        requests_without_0 = await database.getAllRequestsWhereTime_is_not_0()

        print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + 'Запуска task с проверкой слотов пользователей')
        tasks = [check_requests(user) for user in users] #####
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + f'Запуска task с уменьшение duration на -1 у запросов который не имеют duration 0 ({len(requests_without_0)})')
        tasks3 = [minus_time(request) for request in requests_without_0] #####
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks3)

        print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + f'Запуска task с отправкой сообщение запросов, которые имеют duration 0 ({len(requests_with_0)})')
        tasks2 = [send_message_request(request) for request in requests_with_0] #####
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks2)


        print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + 'Запуска task с проверкой время премиума у пользователей')
        #обновляем время на задержку созадния запроса для пользователя
        tasks4 = [checkpremium(user) for user in users] #####
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks4)
        print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + 'Конец круга')
```

Вот код где запускается эта функция.

```
bot.loop.create_task(startTimerRequests())
bot.run(token)
```

Использую следующие библиотеки:

nextcord,
asyncio,
aiohttp,

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду, что хотите, чтобы `tasks1` и `tasks2` выполнялись «одновременно», значит логично их засунуть в один gather, наверное?

Comment: Кстати, да. Спасибо, попробую